# Dust.js template with simple logic

Tags: templates, dust.js

I have some JSON data:

```
 {
         "title": "Available Cars",
             "names": [{
             "name": "Ford",
                 "image": "./images/ford.png",
                 "flags": "./images/us.png",
                 "description": "Make Average Cars",
                 "detail": [{
                 "Profile": "Big US company",
                     "Background": "Bad"
             }]
         }, {
             "name": "BWM",
                 "image": "./images/bmw.png",
                 "flags": "./images/gm.png",
                 "description": "Make Great Cars",
                 "detail": [{
                 "Profile": "MediumGermancompany",
                     "Background": "Good"
             }]
         }, {
             "name": "VW",
                 "image": "./images/vw.png",
                 "flags": "./images/gm.png",
                 "description": "MakeGoodCars",
                 "detail": [{
                 "Profile": "LargeGermancompany",
                     "Background": "Very Bad"
             }]
         }]
     }
```

And a template that looks like this:

```
<div><ul><li>{title}</li>{#names}<li data-name=\"{name}\"><a href=\"{name}\"> <h4><img src=\"{flags}\">Name :{name}</h4><p>{description}</p></a></li>{~n}{/names}</ul></div></div>
```

Which creates the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Available Cars</li>
            <li data-name="Ford"><a href="Ford"><h4><img src="./images/us.png">Name :Ford</h4>

                <p>Make Average Cars</p></a></li>
            <li data-name="BWM"><a href="BWM"><h4><img src="./images/gm.png">Name :BWM</h4>

                <p>Make Great Cars</p></a></li>
            <li data-name="VW"><a href="VW"><h4><img src="./images/gm.png">Name :VW</h4>

                <p>MakeGoodCars</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add some logic that looks at the value of "Background" and renders a button underneath each li based on the value. e.g.

```
If "Background" == "Bad" 
   <button type="button">Button 1</button>
Else If "Background" == "Good"
   <button type="button">Button 2</button>
Else If "Background" == "Very bad""
   <button type="button">Button 3</button>
```

Ive create a jsfiddle that shows this:

http://jsfiddle.net/carlskii/Dam29/5/

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: try using dustjs helpers, for example the select helper.

Comment: You got one thing right, your JSON data about car quality seems correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just update the JSON in javascript? Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var template = "<div><ul><li>{title}</li>{#names}<li data-name=\"{name}\"><a href=\"{name}\"> <h4><img src=\"{flags}\">Name :{name}</h4><p>{description}</p></a><p>Button: {type}</p></li>{~n}{/names}</ul></div></div>"

    var compiled = dust.compile(template, "intro");
    dust.loadSource(compiled);

    var data = {
        "title": "Available Cars",
        "names": [{
            "name": "Ford",
            "image": "./images/ford.png",
            "flags": "./images/us.png",
            "description": "Make Average Cars",
            "detail": [{
                "Profile": "Big US company",
                "Background": "Bad"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "BWM",
            "image": "./images/bmw.png",
            "flags": "./images/gm.png",
            "description": "Make Great Cars",
            "detail": [{
                "Profile": "MediumGermancompany",
                "Background": "Good"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "VW",
            "image": "./images/vw.png",
            "flags": "./images/gm.png",
            "description": "MakeGoodCars",
            "detail": [{
                "Profile": "LargeGermancompany",
                "Background": "Very Bad"
            }]
        }]
    };

    var arr = data.names;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].detail[0].Background == "Bad"){
            arr[i].type = "Button 1";
        }else if(arr[i].detail[0].Background == "Good"){
            arr[i].type = "Button 2";
        }else if(arr[i].detail[0].Background == "Very Bad"){
            arr[i].type = "Button 3";
        }
    }

    dust.render("intro", data, function (err, out) {

        $('#container').html(out).trigger("create");

    });

});
```

See how it works in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amiramix/4wSAL/). If you can't update JSON then you can always create a custom dust base which you can initialize before calling dust.render. See section Context in [the dust guide](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/). It could be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var template = "<div><ul><li>{title}</li>{#names}<li data-name=\"{name}\"><a href=\"{name}\"> <h4><img src=\"{flags}\">Name :{name}</h4><p>{description}</p></a><p>Button: {#type data=detail/}</p></li>{~n}{/names}</ul></div></div>"

    var compiled = dust.compile(template, "intro");
    dust.loadSource(compiled);

    var data = (...); // as in the previous example

    var dustCtx = dust.makeBase({
        type: function(chunk, context, bodies, params){
            var background = params.data[0].Background;
            var output = "undefined";
            if(background == "Bad"){
                output = "Button 1";
            }else if(background == "Good"){
                output = "Button 2";
            }else if(background == "Very Bad"){
                output = "Button 3";
            }
            return chunk.write(output);
        }
    });

    dust.render("intro", dustCtx.push(data), function (err, out) {

        $('#container').html(out).trigger("create");

    });

});
```

Or again on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amiramix/Y2ztc/).